# grid view edited data should be posted to the same row after post back

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've a gridiview with edit functionality. When the user clicks the EDIT button the row data of the grid is posted to the form for edit. And then the user have to press the submit button to add data to the grid again.

I want to post the data to the same row of the grid after edit but I do not know how to do it i.e. if the third row data is edited then on add button click the edited data should be submitted to the third row.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>NAME</label><span class="required">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="200" runat="server" id="txtName" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>GENDER</label><span class="required">*</span>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectGender" runat="server" style="height: 34px;">
        <option value="0">M</option>
        <option value="1">F</option>
        <option value="2">U</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddFamMem" runat="server" Text="ADD" />
    </div>
</div>

<asp:GridView ID="famGrid" 
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    Width="100%"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="famGrid_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S No." ItemStyle-Width="3%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField
            HeaderText="NAME" DataField="Name">
            <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField
            HeaderText="GENDER" DataField="Gender">
            <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
        </asp:BoundField>                                        
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="EDIT" HeaderText="EDIT" ButtonType="Button" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind logic

```
protected void famGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow gvr = famGrid.SelectedRow;
            selectGender.Value = gvr.Cells[1].Text == "&nbsp;" ? null : gvr.Cells[1].Text;
            selectGender.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

 protected void btnAddFamMem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Value.Trim()))
                {
                    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["FamilyTable"];
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Name"] = txtName.Value.Trim();
                    dr["Gender"] = selectGender.Items[selectGender.SelectedIndex].Text;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    BindFamilyGrid();
                }            
        }
```

Suppose, my grid data is ::

```
NAME        GENDER
TSHERIG       M
TONGBA        F
PASNG         M
```

So when I edit second row data, I want to save the edited data again to the same row. Now I am adding the edited data in the end. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: @VDWWD In this tutorial, the edit is done on the grid view rows, but my requirement is not like that. Please read the post first. I've to post the grid data to the form and then do edit and post back data to the grid.